# Magento2 - Set Cron job for particular custom dates

Tags: magento2, cron

I want to update Special Price on promotional time period.
That needs to updated on particular date.
I dont want cron to be run daily, it can be any day in month at 12am in midnight.
I want to add date in system configuration.

Any solution to this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

create your system.xml file first like this

```
<section id="section_id" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
            <label>A meaningful section label</label>
            <tab>A_UNIQUE_ID</tab>
            <resource>VENDOR_MODULE::path_to_the_acl_resource</resource>

            <group id="group_id" translate="label comment" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1">
                <label>A meaningful group label</label>
                <comment>An additional comment helping users to understand the effect when configuring the fields defined in this group.</comment>
                <field id="field_id" translate="label comment" sortOrder="2" type="time" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Start Time</label>
        </field>
            </group>
        </section>
```

now make a note of section_id/group_id/field_id

now create crontab.xml like below

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Cron\Test" method="execute" name="mageplaza_helloworld_cron">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

now replace this line `<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>` with this <config_path>crontab/default/jobs/my_cron_setup_job/schedule/cron_expr</config_path>

so your updated crontab.xml would like this.

add your {{section_id/group_id/field_id}} here created in above system.xml

and add cron expression in admin like this * * * * * and your cron will execute based on your system configuration.
use this website for help related to cron scheduling
https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a simple suggestion , Based on this give your try. Add a condition on your cron file to execute the cron on a specific date which is update from your custom module system configuration. if the date is matched run the file, if not return it

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Ayakil\ModuleName\Cron;
class Test{

protected $logger;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 */
public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

/**
 * Execute the cron
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    //get the date from system configuration

    $date = "Date from your configuration";
    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    if ($today!=$date) { // Here use appropriate date checking method
      return false;
    } else {
      // add your code to run
    }
}
}
```